# Where can I find Database Unit Test Project in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to create unit tests against database queries.

I've seen many tutorials based on earlier versions of Visual Studio where you have the option to unit test your database code, with the pre-test, post-test and test itself.

I can't seem to find it in Visual Studio 2017; when I go to "Tests" it only shows "Unit Test Project (.Net Framework)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server unit tests can be added to a regular unit test project that might also contain tests against c# classes.

You can add a SQL Server unit test to a unit test project by:

1. Right-click the project name.
2. Add > New Item...
3. Go to the SQL Server category
4. Select SQL Server Unit Test

[image]

You can also right-click a stored procedure or function within a database project and select "Create Unit Tests..."

I believe Visual Studio Professional Edition or higher is required with SQL Server Data Tools installed.

[See *Verifying Database Code by Using SQL Server Unit Tests*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851200(v=vs.103).aspx)